# nested On click function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

`.Category-list-L2` is in hidden element when document ready

Refer code:

```js
$("#rn_ProductTriageUpperList li").on("click", function() {
  $("body #guided").hasclass(".Category-list-L2").on("click", function() {
    alert("in");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="rn_ProductTriageUpperList" class="levelone">
      <ul>
        <li>Some Questions</li>
        <li>Some Questions</li>
        <li>Some Questions</li>
        <li>Some Questions</li>
        <li>Some Questions</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="guided" class="leveltwo" style="display: none;">
      <ul>
        <li>Some answers</li>
        <li>Some answers</li>
        <li>Some answers</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Display Some answers related to  Some Questions

Level one is questions,
Level Two is answers

while clicking some Questions
then the related answers should be displayed.

Comment: would be helpful if you add your html code

Comment: [`hasClass`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) returns a boolean so you cannot place a click listener on it

Comment: are you trying to trigger a click event on another element? else what is the logic you're trying to acheive?

Comment: Give us more information, such as your mark up, and what you want to achieve

Comment: we need at least 5 downvotes to reset your reputation. Before that happens, you should try improving the question, imagine that you're in place of the answerers - so wonder about what they need to understand the problem before being able to answer it.

Comment: what's the point of adding an on click event only when an other on click event is occured? This seems **so**  wrong to me

Comment: You don't need second click event to launch your own click event, just launch the event code directly

Comment: answers are already stored in #guided nee to find the related answers by some keyword,when clicking on .levelone <li> have to find the specific answers <li>

Answer (score 0):

If the second button is hidden until the first button is clicked then why do you need to nest them?

You can't click button 2 until button one has been clicked as button 2 wont be there to click.

Just write it like this:

```
    $(".Category-list-L2").on("click",function(){
        alert("in");
    });
```

Comment: hasClass returns boolean